# Ставится ли запятая после почти в «почти, что»?

Tags: синтаксис

Ставится ли запятая в этом предложении:
«Он почти, что сделал.».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, конечно.
Здесь "что" не является союзом, а вместе с "почти" составляет единое целое: оборот в функции обстоятельства (=почти). Легко проверить, убрав "что" - без какой-либо потери смысла или грамматики.

Answer (score 2):

> *Ставится ли запятая в этом предложении: «Он почти, что сделал».*

Нет, запятая здесь не нужна. [***Почти что***](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/223638)  — наречие, синонимичное ***почти***.

***Почти что сделал***  — это то же, что ***почти сделал***.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна, "почти что" - разговорный вариант наречия "почти".

Он почти что сделал.

Из словаря:

**ПОЧТИ**, нареч. Так, что немного недостаёт до чего-л.П. не изменился. П. выздоровела. П. одинаковые платья. П. ничего не ест.  **Почти что**, нареч. Разг. =Почти. Мы с ним почти что ровесники.